# Coffeescript and node.js confusion. require instantiates class?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I'm having trouble trying to get my class working in my node.js file. When I require the module I wrote, the require './module' calls my constructor and gives an error. But I actually want to instantiate later on in the file.

i.e

```
class Mic

constructor: (x) ->
  @t = []
  @t.push x

exports.Mic = Mic
```

and here is my app.coffee file

```
require 'coffee-script'
require './Mic'
```

When I run app.coffee it gives an exception ReferenceError: x is not defined. Which makes sense since its calling the constructor, but why is it calling the constructor even though I havent called new Mic ?

**Edit**
After fixing the indentation

```
class Mic
    constructor: (x) ->
        @t = []
        @t.push x

exports.Mic = Mic
```

and updating my app.coffee to

```
Mic = require './Mic'

m = new Mic 3
console.log m
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR (native)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First thing's first: you don't need the `require 'coffee-script'`—running it with `coffee` is enough; same as running the compiled JavaScript. You don't need the CoffeeScript library available at runtime in your program.

Secondly, the first file appears indented incorrectly; if you want that to be `Mic`'s constructor, indent it one level underneath the `class`, i.e.:

```
class Mic
  constructor: (x) ->
    @t = []
    @t.push x

exports.Mic = Mic
```

Finally, the issue is that `exports` is an **object** of exports. See here:

```
exports.Mic = Mic
```

You've assigned `Mic` to the `exports` object's `Mic` key, so now `exports` in Mic.coffee looks like this:

```
{ Mic: ...your class... }
```

When you say `require './Mic'`, you're getting that object back; in other words:

```
require('./Mic') == { Mic: ...your class... }
```

So you need to do one of the following:

1. Export `Mic` as the entire export of Mic.coffee, and not as a key:

   ```
   module.exports = Mic
   ```
2. Get the entire module out, and then instantiate the `Mic` object within:

   ```
   mic = require './Mic'
   m = new mic.Mic 3
   ```
3. Just take `Mic` out from the `require`'d module:

   ```
   {Mic} = require './Mic'  # equivalent to saying Mic = require('./Mic').Mic
   m = new Mic 3
   ```

Comment: Hey, oops I forgot to replace Dish with Mic. It was a copy and paste problem. I have indented my code and now I am getting a TypeError: object is not a function at Object.CALL_NON_FUNCTION_AS_CONSTRUCTOR . The code does not instantiate automatically till I call mic = new Mic 3 when then gives the previous error.