# Class instantiation

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I followed this example: [Coffeescript and node.js confusion. require instantiates class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10772102/coffeescript-and-node-js-confusion-require-instantiates-class), but it doesn't seem to work - the error is `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, so I must be doing something wrong. I have a simple coffee-script executable. Here are my steps:

Create a folder structure:

appmq

- my_executable
- my_class.coffee
- package.json

The file contents:

`package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "appmq",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "xxxxxx",
    "repository": "",
    "author": "Frank LoVecchio",
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "bin": {"appmq": "./my_executable"}
}
```

`my_executable`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
{CommandLineTools} = require './my_class'
cmdTools = new CommandLineTools()

cmdTools.debug()
```

`my_class`:

```
class CommandLineTools

  debug: () ->
    console.log('Version: ' + process.version)
    console.log('Platform: ' + process.platform)
    console.log('Architecture: ' + process.arch)
    console.log('NODE_PATH: ' + process.env.NODE_PATH)

module.exports = CommandLineTools
```

I then install the application via:

`sudo npm install -g`

Then I run the application (which produces the error I noted above):

`appmq`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris is right in his answer, but it's got nothing to do with whether you have an explicit constructor in your class but rather what you are exporting.

If you want to export a single class like this:

```
module.exports = CommandLineTools
```

Then, when you `require`, what is returned will be what you assigned to `module.exports` above, i.e.:

```
CommandLineTools = require './my_class'
```

And this will work. What you are doing, is exporting in the manner described above, but you are using CoffeeScript's [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring):

```
{CommandLineTools} = require './my_class'
```

which compiles to the js:

```
var CommandLineTools;
CommandLineTools = require('./my_class').CommandLineTools;
```

Which fails, because the `require` call will *not* return an object with the property `CommandLineTools`, but rather `CommandLineTools` itself. Now, if you wanted to use the destructuring assigment above, you would have to export `CommandLineTools` like this:

```
exports.CommandLineTools = CommandLineTools
```

I hope this will shed some light on the matter. Otherwise, ask away in the comments!

Comment: Jup, you're right. Dont know what came to my mind with the constructor 0_o

Answer (score 1):

<s>You don't have a constructor in your class.</s> Exchange

```
{CommandLineTool} = require './my_class'
```

with

```
CommandLineTool = require './my_class'
```

<s>or write a (empty) constructor.</s>